# Why in deep learning or another AI technique python is used rather than other languages?

Tags: machine-learning, python, java

I want to know, why python? Instead of C#, Java, C\C++ and so on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answers

1. **Tooling.** Python has fantastic math, statistics, and linear algebra libraries.
2. **Less Code, Same Result.** Python provides quick and simple ways of achieving programming solutions compared to C#, Java, C++, etc. This means you'll write less code and achieve the same result.

Comment: Likely contributing factors are poor performance (Java), platform/vendor attachment (C#), and complexity (C++). Python is easily learned, open source, and has good performance.